Middle of Nowhere
This is part 77 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.

Dear Puzzling,
This is a Yin-Yang sudoku. Fill the central 9x9 grid with the digits 1–9 so that each digit appears exactly once in every row, column and 3x3 box. Shade some cells in the full-sized grid so that all shaded cells are orthogonally connected, all unshaded cells are orthogonally connected, and no 2x2 area in the grid is fully shaded or unshaded. Cells marked with white circles, as well as every cell containing a number 1–4 in the solved sudoku, must be unshaded. Cells marked with grey circles, as well as every cell containing a number 6–9 in the solved sudoku, must be shaded. Cells containing a 5 can be either shaded or unshaded. The solved grid forms a maze with the given start and end points; the blue letters outside the sudoku grid are used to spell out the final answer.
Today I have visited an extremely ancient settlement in the middle of desert, to see the creative ways in which old civilisations dealt with the unbearable heat. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.

Solve on Penpa+

Gladys will return in Rectangled.

Most of the start is Yin-Yang. In addition to no 2x2 all shaded or unshaded, the connectivity rule implies there can be no Battenburgs, i.e. a 2x2 with two shaded cells on one diagonal, and two unshaded cells on the other. Iterating these basic rules, and using connectivity to force R7C8 to be unshaded, we can do a fair bit of easy shading, and pencil sudoku digits by the unshaded 1-5, shaded 5-9 rule:

 

Now look in box 1 of the sudoku:

 R2C2 cannot be unshaded. If it were, then by the Battenburg rule R3C1 and R3C3 would both be shaded forcing all of R1C1, R1C2 and R1C3 to be unshaded. This would give six unshaded cells in the top row of the sudoku, which cannot happen. This forces R3C1 and R3C3 to be unshaded by the 2x2 rule, and also forces R2C6-R2C9 to all be unshaded, since we already have 5 shaded cells in R2. R2C6 and R2C9 resolve as 1 and 3, respectively. Now we know R1C1-R1C3 contains exactly 2 unshaded cells (box forces at least 2, row forces at most 2), which forces R1C5 to be shaded and not 5, since the 5 in row 1 must be unshaded. Moreover, we know the 5 in box 1 must be shaded. Progress thus far:


In box 4:

 R4C3 is shaded by 2x2, then R5C3 is shaded by Battenburg. This gives us a 6/8/9 triple in row 5, which forces the remaining cells to be a 1/2/4 triple, all of which must be unshaded. R5C8 resolves as 2, which looks up into box 3. The Battenburg rule forces the 5 in box 4 to be unshaded, and the 2x2 rule makes R6C3 unshaded. Battenburg forces R4C2 shaded, and counting makes R4C1 unshaded.

 Looking across row 4, we have 5 unshaded cells, forcing R4C8 and R4C9 to be shaded. Of the four shaded cells in this row, only R4C8 can be 8, which looks up into box 3. Progress thus far:


Box 8:

 The Battenburg rule forces R9C5 to be unshaded, which leaves 5 unshaded cells in column 5. Hence the 5 in this column must be unshaded, which resolves the remaining shaded digits. The only place for 2 in column 5 is R8C5. Now the 2x2 rule forces R9C4 to be shaded, meaning the 5 in column 4 and box 8 must be shaded. This forces R3C4 to be 2, and sudoku also forces R5C6 to be 8.

 Now in box 9, the 8 is surrounding by unshaded cells, forcing R8C8 to be shaded. This gives 5 shaded cells in the row, making R8C2 and R8C3 unshaded. The grid thus far:


Box 6:

 R6C8 must be unshaded: were it shaded, R6C9 would also have to be shaded by the Battenburg rule, giving six shaded cells in R6. Now the 2x2 rule forces R6C9 to be shaded. As there are now 5 shaded cells in box 6 and row 6, the 5 in this box/row must be shaded and we can alter pencilmarks appropriately. This leaves the only spot for a 5 in box 5 as R4C5. The 4 from box 3 looks down, resolving the unshaded digits in box 6.

 Now look in box 9. The only place for a 6 is R9C7, so this cell is shaded, forcing R9C8 to be unshaded. Thus the 5 in the box is unshaded, forcing R8C8 to be 7, and fixing the shaded cells in row 8. This yields a 5/8 pair in box 8, which looks up and yields a number of knock-on sudoku deductions. Progress:


Box 1:

 The 1/3/4 triple in column 1 looks up, removing 1 as a candidate from R1C1, and forcing R1C2 to be 1. Thinking outside the box, we see a border of shaded cells that almost surround this 1, meaning connectivity forces R1C3 to be unshaded as well, so the 1 can escape. This resolves the digits as well. We now have five shaded cells in column 1, so R7C1 must be unshaded and thus a 2. Battenburg now forces R7C2 to be unshaded, and thus a 3, forcing R9C2 to be shaded. The 6 in R9C7 looks left, resolving the shaded digits in column 2. We get a lot of easy sudoku follow-up from setting R4C2 to 6, resolving all the 6s and 9s in the puzzle. In particular, we find R9C3 is 8, and easy forces finish the sudoku digits. The grid:


On to the yin-yang:

 Looking right of box 3 of the sudoku, the cell next to the three must be shaded by 2x2, and this must escape up. Battenburg forces the cell two right of the 1 to be unshaded, then 2x2 shades the K; it must escape down.

 Now look above box 1 of the sudoku. We noted the nearly surrounded unshaded cells earlier; this forces the cell above the 4 to be unshaded. Battenburg forces the cell above the 9 to be shaded, meaning we must continue the unshaded string to its left up. Back in the box, the cell left of the 6 must be unshaded, as must the cell left of the 4. Then the cell left of the 3 is shaded. The grid thus far:


Some meta action:

 Look at the bottom right corner of the grid. There's a bit of a cage of unshaded cells, but the 2x2 rule means there must be some unshaded cells inside, so the whole right corner must be shaded to give them some way out.  Similarly, the three cells starting from the P moving up must also be shaded, and now we see the two cells right of the 9 must also be shaded. Now we can start back down, shading/unshading cells according to 2x2 and Battenburg, yielding:


We can do more:

 The cell below the 3 in box 9 is shaded so the shaded cell on the C can escape, with Battenburg forcing the cell below the 6 to be shaded as well.

 Going to the upper left corner, we see the cell NW of the 7 must be unshaded by 2x2, and it must escape up. Battenburg forces the cell left of the Y to be shaded. The cell above the 8 in row 1 of the sudoku must be shaded by Battenburg, and we can some knock-ons to its right to the X.

 And finally, we can resolve the last 5 in the sudoku grid...it must be shaded, otherwise the shaded region in the lower right corner would be isolated. With this, we now have a line of shaded cells from the rightmost cell of R6 (of the whole grid) almost touching another edge of the grid at two points: above the shaded E in R2C5, and left of R3C2. So we must have an unshaded buffer for the unshaded cells in the upper right to escape. Moreover, in the upper left 2x2, we must have a shaded cell, but it cannot be either R1C1 or R1C2 without disconnecting the unshaded cells, so it must be R2C2. Knock-on deductions finish the corner. Progress thus far:


Look in the upper right:

 Look at the shaded O. These need to escape either up or to the right. If they go right, they must get to the edge, and eventually come around to the line of three shaded cells at the top edge of the sudoku, which would block off the unshaded cells from connecting...indeed, this logic shows that the entire border of the upper right must be unshaded. With some easy 2x2 deductions, this resolves the entire upper right corner. But now I remember the most important meta-yin-yang deduction: the edge of the border must have one string of shaded, and one string of unshaded. So in fact, the entire lower left corner must be unshaded as well. This gives:


Now we can pretty much groove the rest with connectivity:

 The shaded region containing the 8 in row 1 of the sudoku escapes up. The W is shaded by 2x2, and connects right; 2x2 resolves the rest of the corner. The shaded region with the W escapes the sudoku grid through the 5 in row 9, and the rest falls easily. The finished yin-yang:


The maze:

 

The answer:

 Gladys is in Ghadames, in Libya!

